# Dijkstra algorithm in weighted graph in Java with big graph

Tags: java, memory, optimization, dijkstra

My task is to write a program to calculate shortest time it takes to go from node A(start) to node B(end) on a weighted graph(I'm using dijkstra algorithm). 
Time requirement is 2 seconds on memory limit is 64 MB and I can assume that entered data is valid
First line has 4 whole numbers:
Amount of nodes M(2 ≤ M ≤ 20000)
Amount of edges(connections) N(0 ≤  N ≤ 50000)
Start node A(0 ≤ A < M) and end node O (0 ≤ O < M).

Next N lines has connection info represented with three whole numbers:
connected computers and the time between them in milliseconds(edge weight).
My code doesn't pass all the tests. If i test my code with a big graph then it fails as heap memory runs out(about 900MB on my machine).
**My problem**: How do i optimize my code so it fits into requirements?
Would using adjacency list be enough?
My code is this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Route3 {
  public static int minDistance(ArrayList<Long> mindist, ArrayList<Boolean> visited){
    long min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    int minindex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < mindist.size(); i++) {
        if(!visited.get(i) && (mindist.get(i) <= min)) {
            min = mindist.get(i);
            minindex = i;
        }
    }
    return minindex;
}
public static long dijkstra(long[][] graph, int start, int end) {
    int computers = graph.length;
    ArrayList<Boolean> traversed = new ArrayList<>(); //Hold traversed nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < computers; i++) {
        traversed.add(i,false);
    }
    ArrayList<Long> mindist = new ArrayList<>(); //Holds mindistances to nodes based on index
    for (int i = 0; i < computers; i++) {
        mindist.add(i,Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    mindist.set(start,(long)0);

    for (int i = 0; i < computers; i++) {
        int min = minDistance(mindist,traversed);
        if(min == -1) return mindist.get(end);
        traversed.set(min,true);
        if(min == end) return mindist.get(min) == Long.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : mindist.get(min); //Error check
        for (int j = 0; j < computers; j++) {
            if(!traversed.get(j) && graph[min][j] != 0 && mindist.get(min) + graph[min][j] < mindist.get(j)) {
                mindist.set(j,(mindist.get(min) + graph[min][j]));
            }

        }

    }
    return mindist.get(end) == Long.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : mindist.get(end);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int computers = in.nextInt(); //nodes
    int connections = in.nextInt(); //edges
    int start = in.nextInt();
    int end = in.nextInt();

    long[][] graph = new long[computers+1][computers+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < connections; i++) {
        int x = in.nextInt();
        int y = in.nextInt();
        long t = in.nextLong();
        graph[x][y] = t;
        graph[y][x] = t;
    }
    if(connections == 0) {
        System.out.println(-1);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    long dist = dijkstra(graph,start,end);
    if(dist != -1) System.out.println(dist);
    else System.out.println(-1);
 }
}
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: "*Would using adjacency list be enough?*" - Why not try? Generally, different graph representations are optimized for different kind of graphs. An adjacency list has linear space in N iff. the degree of all node is limited by a constant (e.g. "no node has more than five connections").

Comment: The max number of nodes vs. the max number of edges tells me that an adjacency list is probably going to be more efficient here.  An adjacency matrix requires memory equal to the number of nodes squared, but thanks to your problem constraints you know that you are guaranteed to have no more than 50000 edges, which is only 2.5 times the number of nodes in the worst case.

Comment: Thanks! Using adjacency list actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you'll have to find a better way to hold the graph information. This line:

```
long[][] graph = new long[computers+1][computers+1]
```

could take up to 20001*20001*8 bytes, that is 3GB!

As your net has few connections per node I'd suggest storing the graph as a HashMap of HashMaps of connections:

```
class Connection {
    int nodeA, nodeB;
    long time;
}

HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Connection>> graph;
```

It may sound less efficient, but you are saving all the blank edges. Then you add the Connection to the graph indexed by both nodes (nodeA and nodeB):

```
void addConnection(Connection c)
{
   HashMap<Integer, Connection> subgraph = graph.get(c.nodeA);
   if(subgraph == null)
       subgraph = new HashMap<>();
   subgraph.put(c.nodeB, c);

   HashMap<Integer, Connection> subgraph = graph.get(c.nodeB);
   if(subgraph == null)
       subgraph = new HashMap<>();
   subgraph.put(c.nodeA, c);
}
```

And retrieve the connection descriptor like:

```
long getConnection(int nodeA, int nodeB)
{
    ArrayList<Connection> subgraph = graph.get(nodeA);
    if(subgraph == null)
        return 0L;
    Connection c = subgraph.get(nodeB);
    if(c == null)
        return 0L;
    return c.time;
}
```

This should make your program slower but much more memory efficient.

WARNING: The code is not tested, it's just for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

When the size of the graph is large, in-memory single-machine computing methods often face **the embarrassment of OOM**. Instead of spending a lot of time on performance optimization, I recommend that you try some ready-made graph computing systems, such as **GraphScope**. GraphScope is a large-scale one-stop graph computing system open sourced by Alibaba, which can basically meet all your needs for graph computing。

Since you are more familiar with Java, why not try using **[GRAPE-JDK](https://github.com/alibaba/GraphScope/tree/main/analytical_engine/java)** provided by GraphScope？ It provide a user-friendly Java API, and achieves performance comparable to c++ implementations for many graph algorithms.
You can make use of [the sample implementation of SSSP](https://github.com/GraphScope/gs-algos).

For more information about **GRAPE-JDK**, please check this blog[Breaking the Language Barrier in Large Scale Graph Computing](https://graphscope.io/blog/tech/2023/06/19/Breaking-the-Language-Barrier-in-Large-Scale-Graph-Computing).

Disclaimer: I'm an author of GraphScope.